# Which column will become foreign key when we made a compete table as a foreign key to one of the column of other table in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

```
class Webpage(models.Model):
   topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=264,unique=True)
   url = models.URLField(unique=True)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.name

class AccessRecord(models.Model):
   name = models.ForeignKey(Webpage)
   date = models.DateField()

   def __str__(self):
       return str(self.date)
```

Here in my accessrecord name column which column from Webpage table will become my foreign key??
Please explain how this is working.

because in sql query we explicitly define which column is going to become foreign key.

Comment: If you do not specify the field then Django will use the primary key of the related model. If you do not specify a field as the primary key then Django will create an auto-incrementing integer field named "id" and use it as the primary key. So, the "id" column will be used in your case

Answer (score 0):

The name of the AccessRecord is going to be able to access all the data of the table/model "Webpage" and the topic of Webpage is going to be able to access all the data of the table/model "Topic" Meaning that the value of the name of Access Record is going to become one to the Webpage and you will be able to see the name of the Webpage in access Record because you returned self.name in Webpage model.